# How to match the character class [:alpha:] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all alphabetic characters (not only `[a-zA-Z]`, but really all of them including `ö, ß, â, ç, Æ, Å, Ĺ, Ĩ, Ÿ, Ș, њ, ѝ, Ц, ت, ר`). In other programming languages there is character class named `[:alpha:]` for this, because it is virtually impossible to name all alpha characters from all alphabets in brackets.

`\w` doesn't help because it includes digits and underscore. I need letters only without digits, punctuation, spaces.

Comment: I recommend to have look at [Javascript + Unicode regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Comment: Related: [javascript regex posix character class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31280913/991073), and answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), use. It has support for [Unicode](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode). Otherwise you have to enumerate the ranges yourself.

Comment: So actually, I haven't missed anything, current JavaScript is plain unable to to it without additional libraries or enumerating lots of Unicodes.