# Does Javascript RegExp support POSIX expressions?

Tags: javascript

I have a password `<input>` box in a `<form>` element my html body

When a user click on the submit button in the sign up form, **I can get javascript** to determine whether the string the user typed in the password box is a  combination of  alphabet and/ or numbers  by using the following code

```
$("#password1").val().match(new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z1-9]{1,}/));
```

However when I tried using the expression below, it returns "null" which gives me the impression that POSIX expressions are not supported in javascript... or is it somewhere along the line I am missing something?

```
$("#password1").val().match(new RegExp(/[[:alnum:]]{1,}/));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posix expressions such as `:alnum:` [are not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), though some other backslash-escaped character classes (like `\w` for word characters including alphanumeric characters and the underscore) are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX character classes are not supported, but you can find JavaScript equivalents to them here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html